# onchange listener to a querySelectorAll for multiple checkbox element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add an event onchange listener to a list of checkboxes such that when checked, the label text crosses out. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```js
let todoItem = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
let checkItem = document.querySelectorAll('.checkItem');

for (let i = 0; i < checkItem.length; i += 1) {
  for (let k = 0; k < todoItem.length; k += 1) {
    checkItem[i].onchange = () => {
      if (checkItem[i].checked === true) {
        todoItem[k].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
      } else {
        todoItem[k].style.textDecoration = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="container">one
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>

  <label class="container">two
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>

  <label class="container">three
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>
</div>
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a couple things are going on here. First of all, you are running through two loops, basically saying: for each checkbox, set it's listener to toggle label 1. Then set it's listener to label 2. Then label 3. Secondly, by assigning `checkItem[i].onchange = [Fn]`, you're overriding any previous value it had, which is why you're only ever seeing the last label toggled instead of all three. So essentially, the outcome of your loops looks like this:

1. Set checkbox 1's listener to toggle label 1.
2. Set checkbox 1's listener to toggle label 2, overriding it's previous listener.
3. Set checkbox 1's listener to toggle label 3, overriding it's previous listener.
4. Set checkbox 2's listener to toggle label 1.
5. Set checkbox 2's listener to toggle label 2, overriding it's previous listener.
6. Set checkbox 2's listener to toggle label 3, overriding it's previous listener.
7. Set checkbox 3's listener to toggle label 1.
8. Set checkbox 3's listener to toggle label 2, overriding it's previous listener.
9. Set checkbox 3's listener to toggle label 3, overriding it's previous listener.

Removing the inner loop and just reusing the same index will solve your problem. However, I would recommend going a step further and actually assigning the event listener using `addEventListener`. That way, additional listeners can be added in the future without interfering with existing functionality. Example below.

```js
let todoItem = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
let checkItem = document.querySelectorAll('.checkItem');

for (let i = 0; i < checkItem.length; i += 1) {
  checkItem[i].addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (checkItem[i].checked === true) {
      todoItem[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    } else {
      todoItem[i].style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="container">one
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>

  <label class="container">two
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>

  <label class="container">three
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop is the problem, you iterate all the labels until the last one and apply that as the `onchange` event to each checkbox, so the last label is always getting the line through it, no matter which checkbox is checked, since there are the exact same amount of labels as there are checkboxes, get rid of the inner loop:

```
let todoItem = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
let checkItem = document.querySelectorAll('.checkItem');

for (let i = 0; i < checkItem.length; i += 1) {
    checkItem[i].onchange = () => {
      if (checkItem[i].checked === true) {
        todoItem[i].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
      } else {
        todoItem[i].style.textDecoration = 'none';
      }
    }
}
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rbcLm03g/

Answer (score 1):

Don't expand code too much, write code like this:

```js
let checkItem = document.querySelectorAll('.checkItem');
[...checkItem].forEach((cb)=>{ // Array.from().forEach
  cb.addEventListener("change", function(){
    if(this.checked===true){
      this.parentElement.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }else{
      this.parentElement.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="container">one
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>

  <label class="container">two
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>

  <label class="container">three
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkItem">
 </label>
</div>
```